# Unable to send both File as well as a string in Socket Programming

Tags: android, python, sockets

I am trying to send file from my PC to android
For PC i am using Python Socket Server Code which ask for pc user to enter path and then sends the file to android mobile

Location of file selected is then saved to filename variable as "C:/new_image.jpg"

Till now I have been able to send and receive file (PC is connected via Android Hotspot) and saving it as "temp_file" on android

Now I want to receive the file name and its extension from server itself 
i tried doing

```
conn.send(filename)
```

But then on android I am receiving null value in Toast

I am new to this socket programming and sorry for poor programming

Here is my Python Code

```
import socket,thread
from collections import deque
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

host=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port=54603
s=socket.socket()
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
print filename
print "below s.listen %s" %host
def handleclient(conn):
    f=open (filename, "rb") 
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
        conn.send(l)
        l = f.read(1024)


    print "file has been sent! Now sending path of file"
    conn.send(filename)                                 #this is where null in android
    print "sent path"
    conn.close()
while True:
conn,addr=s.accept()
print 'connected to ',addr
thread.start_new_thread(handleclient,(conn,))
```

and here is my android receiving code

```
 socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);


            DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                    + getPackageName() + "/temp_file"
            );


            File dirs = new File(f.getParent());

            if (!dirs.exists())
                dirs.mkdirs();

            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            byte buf[] = new byte[10240];
            int len=0;
            while ((len = is.read(buf)) != -1)
            {
                bos.write(buf, 0, len);
                bos.flush();

            }


            fos.close();
            bos.close();

          //TIll now received the file as temp_file but not extension
          // Now next part i am trying to get extension


            result11=is.readLine();           // here reading null
           // result11=result11.substring(result11.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

          /*  File from = new File(dirs,"temp_dhruvit");
            File to = new File(dirs,result11);
            if(from.exists())
                from.renameTo(to);
            d1.close();
            is1.close(); */

            is.close();
            socket.close();
```

Comment: You did check the file size of sent and received file? The received file is longer by the file name.

Comment: @greenapps The size of file is same as of original file and i am able to open it but then i have to manually select type of file to open with.  Since i already close the file by fos.close(); and then read the filename

Comment: `dirs.mkdirs();`. Check the return value of mkdirs() and do not continue is false.

Comment: Sorry but i do not believe that both files are equal in length. The file on the receiving side will contain the filename at end. The receiving side has no idea what is coming and writes all to file. Including filename. Well file path.

Comment: `f.createNewFile();`. Remove that. The File output stream will create the file.

Comment: `Now next part i am trying to get extension`. No your python code is sending a complete Windows file path. You better only send the file name.

Comment: You also better send the file name first so the receiver can use it to save the file under the same name.